# Doesn't save a text file after closing the program

Tags: python, file, text, save

I'm currently stuck on a saving issue. I want to create levels for a game and I'd like to build and **modify** them in a pygame program, then save them in the form of a string in a .txt file.
For now, I managed to open **an existing** file named "level_n.txt", delete the old level I want to overwrite, and write the new level matrix in the text file.

At this point, everything works perfectly.

If I modify the text file, close it, re-open it **in the same program run**, and print the level, the changes were saved.

Here is my problem: when I close my whole program and re-open it, the level isn't changed, and when I open the text file of the level manually, the changes aren't here either.

So from my perspective, it looks like Python creates a copy of the file in the RAM, overwrites it, uses it, but when it closes, the text file doesn't save.

I've included the part where I write the text, and a level example just in case. (I've tried to write the text using w, w+, r+, a+, none of these solve my issue)

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #checks for save
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    with open('level'+str(n+3)+'.txt', 'w+') as f:
                        f.truncate(0)
                        for i in range(0,len(level)):
                            lin = ""
                            for j in range(0,len(level[0])):
                                lin = lin + str(level[i][j][0])+","+str(level[i][j][1]) + "."
                            lin = lin[:-1]+"\n"
                            f.writelines(lin)  
                        
                    with open('level'+str(n+3)+'.txt', 'r') as g:
                        level = [[[int(num[0]),int(num[2])] for num in line.split('.')] for line in g]
                        print(level)
                    print("contents saved ! (maybe)")
```

Inside "level4.txt"

```
1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3
1,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,2
1,2.0,0.1,1.0,0.1,2
1,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,2
1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3
```

Python 3.8, window 10

Comment: Don't use close() as the files will be closed automatically because you opened them by `with`

Comment: remove `f.close()` and `g.close()`

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I removed the close() statements (edited) but my problem persists and I don't see any change to my program's behaviour.

Comment: Do you see the program print out "contents saved ! (maybe)"?  If you don't see that, something is wrong.  There is no exception handling, so any exception in the block of code could cause the file update to fail.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that something else in your program restores the file contents later? Also: rather than opening as `w+` and truncating, why not just open as `w`? Rather than `.writelines` for a single string, why not just `.write`? Rather than looping to build the string, why not use `','.join` and `'.'.join` with a comprehension (matching the way the input is read)?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. We aren't interested in conversational language in the question - we just want the question. "Interesting" doesn't matter - what matters is that the question is properly asked, specific, clear and unique. To that end, please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Check: can you still cause the problem if you remove other parts of your program? If you hard-code the call instead of waiting for a keypress? If you don't use Pygame? If you read and write something simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to the file instead of just the name of the file and it should work fine For example:

```
with open(r'E:\Project\level'+str(n+3)+'.txt', 'w+') as f:
```